# How can I watch an age-restricted YouTube video without logging in?

Tags: youtube

I want to watch an age-restricted video on YouTube.

I'm currently using my computer on non-password protected public wifi, meaning that I don't want to login with my YouTube username and password due to security concerns. I've also had times where I'm using private browsing, and I wanted to avoid adding the video to my account's watch history.

I know that YouTube age restrictions [don't apply on embedded videos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288854/351462), but I'm trying to watch a video which hasn't been embedded on any site.

**Is there any way I can watch an age-restricted video on YouTube without logging in?**

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise As an example, [this age restricted video of profanity on a Southwest Airlines flight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dLS8_xM2LI). It can only be viewed if the user is logged in, or if [embedded on another website](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288854/351462).

Comment: Maybe set up an OpenVPN server at home (or on a VPS) so you don't have to worry about a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Well there's probably no getting around it at work (and why are you watching age restricted videos at work anyway?), but a VPN will still work while using private browsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get around age-restricted YouTube videos by changing the URL of the video. All you need to do is change it to this version:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/{video-id}
```

The `{video-id}` part is taken from the end of the normal page you land on.

For example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dLS8_xM2LI
```

In this, `8dLS8_xM2LI` is the video-id, and you can get around the age-restriction by going directly to the full screen mode:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/8dLS8_xM2LI
```

Comment: When I try [`https://www.youtube.com/v/8dLS8_xM2LI`](https://www.youtube.com/v/8dLS8_xM2LI) in Google Chrome, it prompts me to download the video as a Shockwave Flash Object.

Comment: Do you have the latest Chrome version? Try another browser, but that prompt seems like they did not get around to making it available in the proper format

Comment: I have the latest Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115. On Internet Explorer 8 the video is embedded properly. (It's a work PC. Don't judge me)

Comment: Chrome is probably set to not play Flash by default unless you can change the settings

Comment: [Chrome disabled flash by default in 2016 to prevent security vulnerabilities](https://www.theverge.com/2016/12/9/13903878/google-chrome-block-flash-html5).

Comment: /embed/ does the same as /v/ but is the default now for YouTube, and doesn't require flash.